# Induction principle for higher induction types

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

I am reading the [HoTT book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) and cannot figure out how the induction principe works for the suspension.

Let $A$ be a type.
Then as I understand it from chapter 6.5 of the book, the induction principle for $\Sigma A$ is as follows. Let $P: \Sigma A \rightarrow \mathcal{U}$.
If you have two inhabitants $n:P(N),s:P(S)$
and a function $f: \Pi_{x:\Sigma A} (n =^{P(S)}_{medi(x)} s)$.
You get a section $g:\Pi_{x:A} P(x)$ with $g(N)=n$ and $g(S)=s$.

But if I look in the solutions of the exercises at line 1679 of [github](https://github.com/HoTT/book/blob/master/exercise_solutions.tex),
it states that a function $$f:\Pi_{x:\Sigma A} (n=x) \rightarrow (n =^{P(S)}_{medi(x)} s)$$ is required for the induction.

Which one is correct? Why? Where can is this explained in the book(if it is the one from the exercise)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated at the beginning of section 6.5 of the book, the general induction principle requires $n:P(N)$ and $s:P(S)$ and a function $f:\prod_{a:A} (n =^P_{\mathsf{merid}(a)} s)$ and gives $g:\prod_{x:\Sigma A} P(x)$.  (There are some typos in your statement.)

I cannot find anywhere in the exercise solutions a function with the type that you mention (if it is there, please point me to it), but it looks like the sort of thing that you might get by specializing this to a particular value of $P$.

Comment: I added a line number.

Comment: Ah.  That line is not about the suspension at all; it's about the infinity-sphere defined as a different HIT.

Comment: Ok. But the constructors and suspension look very similar, what part part of the definition of the infinity-sphere as a HIT makes it have a different induction principle?

Comment: The fact that the x in merid(x) belongs to the type S^oo being defined (so the constructor is "recursive".

Comment: Ok I get it. Thank you!